# JsRender, how to render an anonymous array?

Tags: javascript, templates, jsrender

I have an anonymous array being passed into a JsRender template, how do I refer to each element to render them dynamically?

Here is the template code, I have it all set up, I just don't know what variable to pass into the {{for}} tag:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{for /*What goes here?*/}}
        <div id="{{>id}}" class="title">{{>title}}</div>
    {{/for}}
</script>
```

Here is the code to render the template with the data. I don't know the length of the array being passed into the method.

```
$('#template').render([{
    id: 1,
    title: 'first title'
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'second title'
}, {
    id: 3,
    title: 'third title'
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing an array to the JsRender method, then JsRender *will automatically iterate over the array*, and concatenate the result of applying the template to each item in the array.

http://www.jsviews.com/#tmplrender

So you don't need to wrap in `{{for ...}}`. Just write:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div id="{{>id}}" class="title">{{>title}}</div>
</script>
```

Incidentally you ***can*** tell render NOT to render arrays automatically, by passing `true` as second parameter: `$('#template').render(myArray, true)`. Now in that case you would need to tell the template itself to iterate - which you can do by wrapping in either `{{for}}<div>...</div>{{/for}}` (with no parameter) - or, equivalently `{{for #data}}<div>...</div>{{/for}}` (`#data` as parameter).

Answer (score 0):

After some research and initiative I worked out that `#data` represents the current value in JsRender.

Therefore `{{for #data}}` is the correct answer!